# The correct English translation for ～ことがある

Tags: grammar

> アメリカへ行ったことがある。(lit: I have been to America.)

Which is the correct other translation?

A: There **is** a time when I went to America.

B: There **was** a time when I went to America.

Bonus question: Is it possible to say アメリカへ行ったことがあった or アメリカへ行ったことがなかった ?

Comment: What's the difference between A and B?

Comment: @oals: Is there no difference? Why?

Comment: I don't know -- I'm asking you. I can't spot any.

Answer (score 5):

The ことがある grammar structure can be used with both a past and a non-past verb form, but with different meaning.

For the meaning you wish to convey, we can use a past tense verb:
**Vpast +ことがある**

It means literally something like "there was a time when..."

But in terms of English translation, it is best looked at in question form first.

> アメリカへ行ったことがありますか

is the equivalent of "Have you ever been to America?"
Making a statement with these grammar therefore means that you have done or experienced something before.

> アメリカへ行ったことがあります

- "I have been to America (and that experience has stayed with me)"

This is different from アメリカへ行きました　which simply means "I went to America"

Using **Vnon-past +ことがある** expresses something like "there are times when..." and expresses that something happens from time to time.

For example

> 朝ごはんを食べずに学校に行くことがあります

- "There are times when I go to school without eating breakfast".

Answer (score 3):

> ことがある

Means : There is

That usage is meant to say : There is such an event in my life where X happened.

Unless you got the power to travel through time and change history,

> アメリカへ行ったことがあった

Is impossible.
It would mean you had the experience of going there, but you don't have it anymore.

On the other hand

> アメリカへ行ったことがなかった

Is quite natural.
It means that until you went, you had never been there.(It was your first time.)

As far as English go. I feel like "there was" would have a similar meaning to "there is".

Comment: `There such an even in my life...` <- There **is** such an even**t** in my life... ですよね、たぶん…？`until you went, you had never went` <- you had never **been** とか you had never **gone** とはまた違う意味で書かれているんですかね…？

Comment: @chocolate Thank you for your corrections. These are quite embarrassing mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that either translation could be used, especially as an intermediate translation before tidying up the language. For the final translation, though, it is likely that I would use the much simpler "I have been to America [before]."